# How to add a UIImage below UIBarButton item

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiimage

I have a `UIView` that appears on screen when a user taps a `UIBarButtonItem` in my `UINavigationController`. The button already has an image, which works fine.

What I would like to do is when the `UIBarButtonItem` is tapped a small image appears right below it - still partly in the `UINavigationController` - so it looks like a speak bubble has appeared. It seems this would be quite difficult.

Is this possible? Or should I look at just moving the `UIView` down a few points and adding the `UIImage` between the `UIView` and the `UINavigationController`?

I don't want to change the size / high of the `UIBarButtonItem` or its current image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `UIBarButtonItem's` tap event : `Add` on `window`

```
AppDelegate *yourAppDelObj = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate
UIImageView *yourImgView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imagenamed:@"image name here"];
//set frame below UIBarButtonItem
//add tag
[yourImgView setTag:9999];
[yourAppDelObj.window addSubView:yourImgView];
```

`Remove` `addedSubView` from window when `not needed`:

```
//Remove the UIView
UIView *addedImgView = [yourAppDelObj.window viewWithTag:9999];
[addedImgView removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Tested and working. Thank you!!