# Adding UIView to UIWindow not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow

I am trying to add a `UIView`  to `UIWindow` using the `appDelegate` I am using this code:

```
NSArray *myViewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:nil];

UIView *myView = myViewArray[0];

UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];

myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 258, 564);
[myView setTag:100];
[window addSubview:myView];
```

However this doesn't work. If I add it to my `self.view` it works fine. However, I want this view to be onto of all other views when it appears.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**

I used code from my last SO question: [How to add a UIImage below UIBarButton item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503530/how-to-add-a-uiimage-below-uibarbutton-item)

There it worked fine, no problems.

However in this new project which only has a viewDidLoad method and one controller its not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are adding the subview after you've initialised your window, set its rootViewController and called makeKeyAndVisible.

Comment: setting its rootViewController was the issue. Thanks.

Comment: in my case view in visible if I calling from UIModalPresentationFormSheet, in this case it comes behind the presentationed viewController

Comment: How did you set the rootViewController?  Did you just create a uiviewcontroller and put your view into it?

Answer (score 2):

try using `[window bringSubViewToFront:myView];`

Comment: @Tander also use [window makeKeyAndVisible];